# Enclose try-catch in a public method and invoke when needed

Tags: java, try-catch

How to enclose try-catch in a public method and invoke when needed.

I have try-catch in one screen code. I want to invoke it from another screen by calling a method to it that stands public(to the entire application).

Is it possible ? If so how.

Please guide.

[image]

Re edits:

As seen in the below code, second tab pane implementation has been shown,please ignore the syntactic differences one may find with native java(This has been implemented for Blackberry JDE). Implementation constructs remain the same hence please overlook the differences and suggest a logical solution to the problem being faced.

```
  // setup the second tab  
  vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );

 //Initialize grid for publishing results
  grid.add(new LabelField("Name")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });
    grid.add(new LabelField("Total")
    {
       public void paint(Graphics graphics)
       {
         graphics.setColor(Color.CYAN);
         super.paint(graphics);
       }
     });


    grid.setColumnPadding(100);
    grid.setRowPadding(20);


   //TRY CATCH STARTS HERE


   try
                  {
                  //Open or create the database
                    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("database1.db"); 

                    Statement statementG55 = db.createStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GTemp4(gname TEXT,gbal INTEGER)");
                    statementG55.prepare();
                    statementG55.execute();       
                    statementG55.close();

                    Statement statementG56 = db.createStatement("SELECT gname,gbal FROM GTemp4 ORDER BY ROWID DESC");
                    statementG56.prepare();
                    statementG56.execute();

                            Cursor c = statementG56.getCursor();

                            //Get to the row of grid
                             for (int i =1; i < grid.getRowCount(); i++)
                             {
                                    System.out.println("Inside for first loops");
                                    //Get to the column of grid
                                for (int j = 0; j < grid.getColumnCount() ; j++)
                                {
                                   System.out.println("Inside for second loops");
                                   //Get to the row of temp4 table
                                   while(c.next()) 
                                   {

                                      System.out.println("Inside while"); 
                                        Row r;
                                        r = c.getRow();


                                        for (int k = 1; k >=0; k--)
                                        {

                                            System.out.println("Inside for loops");

                                            if(k==0)
                                            {
                                                System.out.println("Retrieving Names");
                                                grid.insert(new LabelField(r.getString(k))
                                                {
                                                    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                                                    {
                                                    graphics.setColor(Color.GOLD);
                                                    super.paint(graphics);
                                                    }
                                                 },i,j);


                                            }  
                                            else
                                            {   

                                                System.out.println("Retrieving other values"); 
                                                String p = "" + r.getObject(k);


                                                grid.insert(new LabelField(p)
                                                {
                                                    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                                                    {
                                                    graphics.setColor(Color.GOLD);
                                                    super.paint(graphics);
                                                    }
                                                 },i,j); 



                                            }   
                                           grid.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE,Color.STEELBLUE,Color.MIDNIGHTBLUE,Color.STEELBLUE));



                                        } 
                                         System.out.println("Exiting while");                        
                                      }

                                      System.out.println("Exiting sec for");
                                      break;
                                  }
                                System.out.println("Exiting first for");
                                break;
                               } 
                               statementG56.close(); 
                               db.close();
                  } 
                  catch(Exception e) 
                  {         
                        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        e.printStackTrace();     
                  }  

    vfm.add(grid);

  nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

  pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
  model.addPane( pane );
```

A big thanks to everyone below who have made a suggestion.

Comment: This question is very unclear (at least to me)

Comment: Post the code you are trying to call and how you would like to call it. This questions seems a little big too vague.

Comment: I'm also not clear on what exactly is required :)

Comment: @All above.Please see the image.I want my try-catch(of pane 2) to execute after a method has been called on clicking the search button from pane 1.Hope i have made it clear.

Comment: @npinti I want to have a public method for the pane 2 try-catch so that i can invoke it on button click from pane 1.

Comment: @Ewald I want to have a public method for the pane 2 try-catch so that i can invoke it on button click from pane 1.I am unclear how to go about enclosing try-catch in a public method and later invoking them.Please guide.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet I have tried using thread implementation to contain the execution of try-catch.But nothing serves the purpose.Please guide.

Comment: Ah, then you should only CALL the search method once you are ready for it to be executed. It should simply THROW and exception, which will then get caught by pane1.  I think. Any code sample perhaps?

Comment: @Ewald I have no issues with the search method executing.The problem is i want to avoid that try-catch of pane 2 from running(it starts publishing junk result).Can you suggest me a way i can have that(pane two's) try catch execute after the pane one's try catch.

Comment: The question here is what triggers the try-catch of Pane2 to be executed? Isn't there a way to avoid that and only have it fire upon an event that's not related to something happening before the search? Could you perhaps show us some sample code? It seems like we don't understand your particular use case and we'd love to help you solve this challenge.

Comment: @Ewald I truly appreciate your interest in finding out an apt solution to my issue.Please find the attached code snippet of my implementation.

Comment: Would a boolean flag, that's set to false, and changed to true at the end of the search function, help at all? Then the code for panel 2 can check the boolean, and only if it's true, display something.  In all honesty, I think one might need to redesign the solution a little bit though, to have two separate methods that are called one after the other (for example, the search can call an update method for pane2 when it is done searching) to ensure no garbage is output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11423/discussion-between-learning-fly-and-ewald)

Comment: @Ewald If i set a bool flag,can its access pertain over to the second pane as well so that i can trigger it there.Also plz guide in detail how exactly does one invoke update statements to a pane

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still cryptic. I am assuming that you have some code which does some searching and then, it publishes the results to some JPanel called `pane2`. What you want is that once the `Search` button is pressed, you call the code.

You could have a method like so:

```
public void doSomeSearching(...) throws Exception //This will allow you to remove the try/catch block from within the method and be able to catch any exceptions in the layer above.
{
     //Do the searching
     //Update panel2
}
```

Then, what you need to do is to add an action listener to your button. This will allow the code to be executed once the button is clicked. (You can find more information on `ActionListeners` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)).

```
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                     doSomeSearching();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                     //Do something when exception is raised.
                }
            }
        });
```

This should allow you to trigger the search functionality when you click the button and handle any exceptions which should arise.

EDIT:

> another try-catch included within pane2 to publish(It keeps running from the start,i.e,doesnt wait for action listener of search button to be executed)`

Having something loop indefinitely is something which should be ideally avoided since this consumes CPU cycles while basically doing nothing. This usually increases the resources your application consumes and might also cause your GUI to hang. If I where you I would have some method which updates `panel2` which you than call once you have done your searching.

That being said, you could have some intermediary variable, such as a string which contains whatever you need to print and your search method continuously updates this intermediary variable.

Comment: Thanks for a response.You have been partially right in understanding my query.As you have noted above "I am assuming that you have some code which does some searching and then, it publishes the results to some JPanel called pane2." Yes it does some searching but it Doesn't publish them to pane 2.In fact i am having another try-catch included within pane2 to publish(It keeps running from the start,i.e,doesnt wait for action listener of search button to be executed).This is the main problem.Can i still use the above code to track down the same.

Comment: Your observation on the CPU cycles consumption is very much right."I would have some method which updates panel2 which you than call once you have done your searching."The fact that i am inserting the values into grid is making it tough for me to programmatically implement what you have suggested.I too share the same opinions as you on somehow updating the panel2.But HOW is what i still wonder.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not recommended.

Instead of placing a generic surrounding try-catch block around your method, you should consider adding the "throws" clause to the declaration of each method you want to handle this way, and then handle all those exception in a higher layer.

Comment: Thanks for a response.How do i throw the exception from another form so that the try-catch statements are executed. Also "higher layer" implies what exactly.